# Issue with opening files in Excel Web App SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel-services, spreadsheet

I am receiving the below message while trying to open an excel file in a document library in SharePoint 2013.
"We're sorry. We can't open the workbook in the browser because it uses these unsupported features.Sheet protection. Do you want to open the file in Excel instead." I have checked the document and no sheet is protected. Do we have any fix in place for this? Please help.